# How to customly convert template arguments

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say I parse a file and will get a string vector as a result which contains various data types. I'm now looking for a function like:

```
template<typename T>
T convertToType(const std::string& str);
```

which can do this conversion. Ideally I should be able to somehow provide my own conversion function, i.e. if T is an own complex type. Is there a way around having to pass it as a parameter everytime?

I was thinking about some sort of:

```
if(typeof(T) == double)
  std::stod(str)
// ...
else
  throw std::logical_error("Type not supported yet!");
```

Another option would be to write a template specialization for each type but this seems to make the use of a template function pretty useless if I have to specify it for each type again...

Comment: How about just a simple [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and let the input operator `>>` handle it?

Comment: What about template specializations?

Comment: Or `boost::lexical_cast`?

Comment: Since user-defined-types will need to provide a conversion function, I fail to see the problem with requiring the user to provide a conversion _specialization_ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>This is turning Joachim's comment into an answer.</sub>

Use `std::istringstream` and let the input operator `>>` handle it.

```
std::istringstream iss(str);
T result;
if (!(iss >> result)) {
    throw std::logical_error("Type conversion failed!");
}
return result;
```

Comment: So to support new/custom types I just have to define a friend overload of std::istringstream& operator>>(std::istringstream& is, MyType& type) ? If yes, then this is exactly what I'm looking for. There will be an error at compile time if one of my new types doesn't implement this operator, right?